# Duplicate component in stimolsoft all page when dataset growth to next page

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

How prevent duplicate component in **stimolsoft** all page when dataset growth to next page

Answer (score 0):

mortazavi
From My Experiences , when you usa dataset or datatable and the data growth to next page,other component repeated at the new page,
you can use dataset in a new page and put it into a panel for better experiences  and when the data growth all the things is correct.
please chek my answer and send your comment to me
thanks